# How to rollback back one method and commit second one in test

Tags: spring, spring-transactions, spring-test

I have some code like follows

```
@Test
@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void testCallDb() {
    rollbackThis();
    commitThis();
}

@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
@Commmit
public void commitThis() {
    //do some work and commit
}

@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
@Rollback
public void rollbackThis() {
    //do some work and rollback
}
```

When I run this, it always rolls back, both methods, i.e. it doesn't commit the `commitThis()` method data. If I put a `@Commit` on `testCallDb()` then both methods are committed, including the `rollbackThis()` method which I want to rollback.

Is there any solution to this either using Spring annotations (preferably) or using some other method?

Update:
As a solution, I used @Huy's suggestion, i.e. removed annotations from `commitThis()` and `rollbackThis()` and changed body of `testCallDb()` to:

```
rollbackThis();
TestTransaction.flagForRollback();
TestTransaction.end();
TestTransaction.start();
TestTransaction.flagForCommit();
commitThis();
```

Comment: The point of the test is to rollback the first one before running the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Spring Framework 4.1, you can interact with test-managed transactions programmatically by using the static methods in TestTransaction.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/transaction/TestTransaction.html

Hope it help in your case.

Comment: I tried https://ramblingabout.wordpress.com/2006/10/29/unit-testing-and-declarative-transactions-with-spring-and-hibernate/ with TransactionTemplate which also works, but your suggestion is cleaner.